# Как отправить данные из html - формы на сервер?

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование

Я абсолютный новичок в вебе, и у меня возник вопрос: допустим, у меня есть сайт на виртуальном хостинге, естественно с хранилищем файлов и базой данных MySql. На одной из страниц сайта есть форма ввода текста с кнопкой "отправить":

```
<form action = '?' method = 'post'>
    <input type = 'text'>
    <input type = 'submit' value = "Send">
</form>
```

Как реализовать отправку введенного пользователем текста на сервер по нажатию на "отправить"?
Я хотел бы обработать этот текст так или иначе, и, например, сохранить в текстовом файле где-то на сервере (или же сохранить в базу данных). Можно ли сделать это посредством JavaScript-a?

Заранее большое спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще это делается при прмощи серверного языка типа php. В методе action="" вы прописываете адрес где лежит код который должен принимать и обрабатывать данные формы. На javaScript вы можете перехватить данные отправляемые с формы, но опять же их нужно будет передавать на сервер для обработки(php, node.js и т.д.).

Comment: спасибо за кусок (можно перехватить) не знал думал только сервер и точка

Answer (score 0):

у input есть 3 атрибута type name value

если указать *value*  то в форме будет отправляться его значение обычно используют
в скрытых input

но чтобы отправилось значение которое ввели в input value указывать не нужно

это будет выглядеть так

```
<form action = 'server.php' method = 'post'>
    <input type = 'text' name="your_name">
    <input type = 'submit' value = "Send">
</form>
```

name="your_name" преобразуется в GET  параметр

то есть в ссылку которая выглядит так ***[https://site.com/server.php?your_name=то_что_ввели_в_инпут](https://site.com/server.php?your_name=%D1%82%D0%BE_%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE_%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8_%D0%B2_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82)***

ну а потом эта ссылка отправляется в ajax запросе через js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    document.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();


        var urlsuccess = new URL("https://site.com/server.php");

        var $that   = e.target;
        var $inputs = $that.querySelectorAll('input');
        var $select = $that.querySelectorAll('select');

        $inputs.forEach(function(input) {

            urlsuccess.searchParams.set(input.name, input.value);

        })

        $select.forEach(function(select) {

            urlsuccess.searchParams.set(select.name, select.value);

        })

        console.log(urlsuccess + "")

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.withCredentials = false;
        xhr.open("POST", urlsuccess, true);
        xhr.send();
    })
})
```

затем в server.php. мы ловим эти GET параметры

```
<?php


echo $_POST['your_name'];
```

а потом уже идет отправка в базу или запись в файл !

Comment: А почему мы ловим GET параметры через $_POST? ))) Я вижу что ajax отправляется при помощи POST, но в метод send() Вы не передали ничего. Несостыковка небольшая

Comment: xhr.open я передал пост ) но можно этот параметр ловить и в $_REQUЕST

Comment: Вообще я указывал на неправильную формулировку.  GET параметры они не просто так называются GET параметрами. Они передаются методом 'GET'. И принимаются на сервере при помощи $_GET. А ваш ajax запрос написан полностью под GET запрос, просто метод почему то указан POST. Для отправки запроса методом POST параметры должны передаваться в качестве обьекта, через метод .send({параметры})

Comment: @fortavey send не принимает объект он принимает строку , как вы собираетесь перевести объект в строку ?

Comment: Как? Как минимум при помощи JSON.stringify. К чему этот вопрос?

Comment: @fortavey   stringify преобразует объект в json  строку  [{"name":"value"}]  а для отправки через send нужна строка GET параметров  "name=value"  , вот и получается что нужен дополнительный костыль